# Is there a bibstyle for the Nature journal?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, bibtex

I'm writing a manuscript to submit to this journal, and I'm using bibtex. Problem is: I can't find any bibliography style files that comply to the demands of the journal. Does anyone know if there's a format for that?

The format requires (for articles being cited):

- Last-name-first authors, with abbreviated first names: `Dylan, B. & Doe, J.`
- Full title, only first word capitalized, no italic, ending with a full stop: `This is a title.`
- Name of the journal in italics: *`Nature`*
- Volume number (and comma) in bold: **`323,`**
- Followed by page and (in curved brakets) year.

So it would end up like this
Dylan, B. & Doe, J. This is a title. *Nature* **323,** 89-92 (1999)

Does anyone know of a bibstyle that complies to these rules?

Comment: Good luck with the submission.  *Nature* isn't what I call a Tex-friendly journal: their copy-editing phase happens in Word.

Comment: I am searching Full Latex template of Nature Publishing group..anyone please help me

Comment: @Syed Bahauddin Alam: Nature does not have one.  They accept Latex submissions but do not encourage them, and they convert Latex to Word for editing.

Comment: You can remove URLs by deleting 'doi' from the naturemag-doi.bst file...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For the traditional BibTeX approach, there is the `naturemag` style, part of the [`nature`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nature) package. Just use:

```
\bibliographystyle{naturemag}
```

If you want to use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), then I have written a style (hopefully) doing the right thing there: [`biblatex-nature`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-nature).

Comment: Thanks, I knew there had to be one. The `naturemag` worked great. The only problem is that it shows URLs. But I'll just remove them manually.

Comment: Is the same package usable for a Nature Methods manuscript? Thanks

Comment: @DavideChicco.it Their [instructions](http://www.nature.com/nmeth/authors/submit/index.html) are vague about requirements for the manuscript. I'd ask the editorial office what formats they'll accept.

Comment: This package doesn't really seem to be very robust.

For example, a Phys. Rev. Lett. citation usually includes a volume and a number. The naturemag package ignores the number at the end. This also happens with Phys. Rev. B. and J. Amer. Ceram. Soc. citations.

Comment: @JohnM I'm not sure what you mean by 'this package', not what the relevance of _e.g._ _Phy. Rev. Lett._ is to the _Nature_ style of citations.

Comment: What I mean is \bibliographystyle{naturemag} does not acknowledge issue numbers, eid numbers, or "number" in (for example) a PRL or Phys Rev B type paper.

Phys. Rev. Applied 4, 014001 <----

You have to trick it and call it a "page" in the .bib file.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Overleaf, you can use Nature-style referencing by putting the following in your preamble

```tex
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

You can see a list of all the available Overleaf biblatex styles [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_bibliography_styles).

*(I know the question specifies bibtex, but it is also tagged with biblatex)*

Comment: The code you wrote needs to be written in the preamble (i.e. before ```\begin{document}```). However, inside the document, you also need to add ```\printbibliography```, otherwise it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested methods didn't work for me to compile locally, but the following one worked for me using local tex compiler:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution proposed by Michael Hall.